# spectral projection

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $T$ be a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$. $P$ is a projection on $H$. Let $E^{|PTP|}(1,\infty)$ be a spectral projection of $|PTP|$. My question is: whether $E^{|PTP|}(1,\infty) \le P$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Since $Z=|PTP|=(PTPTP)^{1/2}$, it is a limit of polynomials of the form $PX_nP$, and so $PZP=Z$.

The spectral projections of an operator always belong to the von Neumann algebra generated by the operator. If $\mathcal M=W^*(|PTP|)=\{|PTP|\}''$, then $E^{|PTP|}(\Delta)\in\mathcal M$ for any Borel set $\Delta$. From the first paragraph we know that $\mathcal M=P\mathcal M P$, so
$$
E^{|PTP|}(\Delta)=PE^{|PTP|}(\Delta)P.
$$
In particular,
$$
PE^{|PTP|}(\Delta)P\leq PIP=P.
$$

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider upvoting answers that you consider useful (not necessarily this one, if you don't want to, but giving reputation is how this site works).

Comment: Pro. Argerami, I have a question : how to conclude that $E^{|PTP|}(\Delta)=PE^{|PTP|}(\Delta)P.$ According $PMP=M$, we only know that there exists $A\in M$ such that $E^{|PTP|}(\Delta) =PAP$, but how to deduce that $A=E^{|PTP|}(\Delta)$?

Comment: As soon as you know that $E^{|PTP|}(\Delta) =PAP$, you have $$PE^{|PTP|}(\Delta) P=P(PAP)P=PAP=E^{|PTP|}(\Delta).$$

Comment: Thanks! If $P,T,\Delta$ are defined as above , does there exist relationships between $E^{PTP}(\Delta)$ and $E^{T}(\Delta)$?

Comment: If by "relationship" you mean a formula, no.